# Spring Integration Asnchronous Webservice call

Tags: spring-integration

Hi is there any examples to call multiple webservices using spring integration asynchronouly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no, but there is `<publish-subscribe-channel>`, when you can have several `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` as subscriber via their `request-channel` and they all will be called for the same `Message`.

You even can collect their responses afterwards using `<aggregator>`.

Although there is `<scatter-gather>` component of the same name EI pattern.

Not sure what is your concern, but you should start from the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/), at least, to see the entire picture.

Comment: Appriciate your input Artem Bilan.My requirment below 1.RestAPI-->(Based on result of first call output)SOAPService
2.RestAPI
3.RestAPI-->(Based on result of 3rd call)

4.Final SOAP Call(This call uses above all service call response to form request)

5.My Service will take output of the 4th call and send back to consumer.

In this flow first 3 service call should be run parallel to improve performance.

I am trying to implemnt splitter-aggreagter pattern to make first 3 calls.Is there any other ways around.
Also we need to send back customized exception in any of the service call.